# Coloring a circle

Tags: circles, coloring, combinatorial-geometry

A circular spintop is colored in blue, red and green. Whenever the spintop is rotated 120 degrees, the pattern of colors looks exactly the same, only that blue becomes red, red becomes green and green becomes blue, like this:

[image]

Prove that there is a blue segment which meets a red segment in one side and a green segment in the other side.

I managed to prove this when the number of segments of each color is finite.

First, because of the rotating condition, it is obvious that all 3 colors must be present in the coloring (for example, if there is a blue point, then there must also be a red point and a green point). Moreover, the number of segments of each color is equal.

Suppose there are $k$ segments of each color. Then the number of endpoints of segments of each color is $2k$. Suppose by contradiction that every blue segment meets only red segments. This means that every endpoint of a blue segment must meet an endpoint of a red segment. But then there is no room for any green segment - a contradiction.

My questions are:

- Is this proof correct?
- Is the statement true also when the number of segments of each color is infinite?

Comment: You have to show the existence of a blue segment, and you haven't used the condition about rotations. Also if you were to colour rational points blue and irrational points green (say the measure is the angle in degrees from some fixed point) you wouldn't have any segments.

Comment: @MarkBennet Because of the rotating condition, all 3 colors must be present in the coloring (for example, if there is a blue point, then there must also be a red point and a green point). Moreover, the number of segments of each color should be equal.

Comment: But, probably there should be a certain topological constraint on the coloring. Maybe that each color should be a closed set (and colors may overlap at their boundaries).

Comment: If you divide the circle into half-open thirds and divide the first third at the points half way, a quarter of the way, one eighth of the way etc from the open end, then you can colour this alternately blue/green. Colouring one third defines the whole colouring. There isn't a well defined colour adjacent to the limit point, yet every point is part of a subsegment with a non-empty interior. I think you need to restrict to a finite number of segments, not necessarily closed (no need to overlap), and your proof is fine.

Comment: A somewhat similar condition ("consistency") is discussed here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00726